# Function in shell script not executed correctly

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

I write a script to start/stop/restart a custom server application.

When starting the daemon server it should make the following:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
### BEGIN INIT INFO
...
...
### END INIT INFO

# Start service
pga_server_start()
{
        /opt/pga/server/server -d
}


# Stop  service
pga_server_stop()
{
        PID=`cat /var/lock/pga_server.lock`
        /bin/kill --signal SIGTERM $PID
}

pga_load_excalibur()
{
        is_loaded=`lsmod | grep excalbr`
        echo "Done"


        if [ -z "$is_loaded" ]; then
                /usr/local/bin/excload
                echo "Driver excalibur loaded."
        else
                echo "Driver excalibur already loaded."
        fi
}

case "$1" in
        start)
        pga_load_excalibur
        pga_server_start
        ;;
...
...
```

Initialy it worked fine. Then I've added the `pga_load_excalibur` function.
Afterward, it does not work anymore.
It never returns from the function `pga_load_excalibur`. 
It seems that the call to `is_loaded=`lsmod | grep excalbr`never returns as the subsequent`echo` is never printed.

However, if I copy/paste this function in a separate shell script...it works.

But if I launch the starter script manually this way:

/etc/init.d/server start
or
service server start

it does not work.
I'm using a Debian Wheezy 7.9 x64.

Although I'm not a schell script, it looks correct. I don't understand why it does not work when it's embedded into this service starter script.

Please note that I've also tried to replace the grep line with:

```
is_loaded=$(lsmod | grep excalbr)
```

But it does not work either.
I'm running out of ideas :(

Z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What  do you get if you run the script in debug mode? try to run it with:

`#!/bin/sh -xv`

That may give some idea of why it's failing, post the output if you can't figure it out

Comment: Good idea ! I didn't think about that. I'll try it tomorrow morning and let you know.

Comment: Well...I changed my code header with yours: 
#!/bin/sh -xv

Everything works fine.

So it seems that using #!bin/sh -e is not the good solution.
-e means that the script immediately exits if a command failed. I still don't understand what's wrong with the command:

 is_loaded=`lsmod | grep excalbr`

Finally, I removed the -xv and simply let #!/bin/sh in the header.
I'm not 100% sastisfied but at least the script works.

Comment: Send the debug info from the -xv and I'll try to help